# Django APIView returns “IndexError: list index out of range” in unit test but works in Postman

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, endpoint, keyerror

I have written an APIView in Django that returns a random line from a database table. When I test it using Postman, I get the response I want. However, when I call the URL of the endpoint in a unit test, I get an “IndexError: list index out of range” error.

Here’s my code:

Endpoint

```
def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        all_the_pickup_id = PickupData.objects.values_list('id', flat=True)
        # if not all_the_pickup_id:
        #     return Response("No pickup lines found.")
        random_id = random.choice(all_the_pickup_id)
        random_pickup = PickupData.objects.get(id=random_id)
        random_line = random_pickup.text
        return Response(random_line)
```

Unit Test Code

```
def test_text_response(self):
        client = APIClient()
        response = client.get('/getPickup/getUnitTest/')
        self.assertEqual(response['Content-Type'], 'application/json')
        print('Get Pickup',response.content)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

How can I fix this error and make my unit test work?

Comment: Please provide a [mre], I don't see any code that would reproduce that error in the code you've shared. Start with sharing the full error traceback. Look at that traceback and see if there are any relevant files you might need to share.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat This is the full trace - Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/k/Desktop/project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 432, in __getitem__
    return self._result_cache[k]
IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is occuring because most likely the `all_the_pickup_id` list is empty. When running unit tests, django creates a test database (separate from your actual database) that is empty. You need to first populate it with some values so that your test works.

Modify your test function like this:

```
def test_text_response(self):
    # create some pick up data
    PickupData.objects.create(**data) # data is a dictionary representing your fields
    PickupData.objects.create(**data2)
    client = APIClient()
    response = client.get('/getPickup/getUnitTest/')
    self.assertEqual(response['Content-Type'], 'application/json')
    print('Get Pickup',response.content)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Or even better create the data in the setUp method, so you can reuse it across test functions.

Comment: thanks for the answer could you tell me if it is possible to call the db model in unit test and use objects.create to fill test database with values? e.g. word = WordModel.objects.latest('date')
        data = {
            'wordOfTheDayinHindi': word.wordOfTheDayinHindi,
            'wordOfTheDayinEnglish': word.wordOfTheDayinEnglish,
            'date': word.date
        }
        WordModel.objects.create(**data)